# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "04/12/2012 14:44"

Tags: exception, numbers, format

I have a programme with the following code:

In XXX.java, I set the SVC_APPR_DT_IN_MILLIS with the date value obtained from a record in Oracle database using **String.valueOf(date.getTime())** strong text. It is stored as a String:

```
private void setApprovalDateProperty(Date date) {
    setAdditionalProperty(SVC_APPR_DT_IN_MILLIS, String.valueOf(date.getTime()));
}
```

In YYY.java, I return the Date back by using **new Date(Long.valueOf())**

```
private Date getApprovalDate() throws ParseException {
    String approvalDateInMillis = this.record
        .getAdditionalProperty(XXX.SVC_APPR_DT_IN_MILLIS);
    return new Date(Long.valueOf(approvalDateInMillis));
}
```

For one of the record, It throws below error, where **"04/12/2012 14:44:38"** is the date of the records in database.

```
For input string: "04/12/2012 14:44"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "04/12/2012 14:44"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:412)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:518)
    at YYY.getApprovalDate(YYY.java:634)
```

I have checked the database, many records in the database can be processed without any problem, except this one. May I know what is the possible cause of this error? I want to simulate the problem but I have no idea how to replicate it. Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the records in the database has been inserted with a faulty version, or that the database is corrupt.

Have you checked what the value of approvalDateInMillis is before the call to Long.valueOf?

You could add e.g.

```
if (!approvalDateInMillis.matches("^[0-9+]$"))
  throw new Error(
    String.format("Invalid approvalDateInMillis format: '%s'", approvalDateInMillis));
```

before the return statement and then continue debugging to see what is really in the database.